# Can I customize the inbuilt browse button in Install4j?

Tags: swing, installation, install4j

I am designing a screen to choose the installation folder directory and when I am adding that installation directory chooser form component it gives an inbuilt browse button in front of the text field. Basically I need to add an image in the browse button and change the position of the button according to my design. Is there any API which I can use to serve my purpose?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As of install4j 8.x, there are no configuration options to achieve this customization.